# Merge-import customers from old DB into new DB

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to import a fresh set of data of customers into an existing database on Magento 1.9.

I don't have access to the backend, thus I cannot use the export functionality.

How could I update all existing customers and create those who aren't there currently by email address via SQL?

How would I proceed here?

Comment: Do you have SSH/CLI access to the server?

Comment: Which datas do you want to transfer : all customer attributes ? all addresses ? passwords ? orders ? ...

Comment: @MattAntley yes, both.

Comment: @JulienLoizelet: everything that has ties to a customer entity

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to MySQL dump out the required tables for customers and their related orders.

A list of the required tables are:

```
customer_address_entity
customer_address_entity_datetime
customer_address_entity_decimal
customer_address_entity_int
customer_address_entity_text
customer_address_entity_varchar
customer_entity
customer_entity_datetime
customer_entity_decimal
customer_entity_int
customer_entity_text
customer_entity_varchar
enterprise_customer_sales_flat_order
enterprise_customer_sales_flat_order_address
enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote
enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote_address
enterprise_sales_creditmemo_grid_archive
enterprise_sales_invoice_grid_archive
enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive
enterprise_sales_shipment_grid_archive
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
sales_flat_creditmemo
sales_flat_creditmemo_comment
sales_flat_creditmemo_grid
sales_flat_creditmemo_item
sales_flat_invoice
sales_flat_invoice_comment
sales_flat_invoice_grid
sales_flat_invoice_item
sales_flat_order
sales_flat_order_address
sales_flat_order_grid
sales_flat_order_item
sales_flat_order_payment
sales_flat_order_status_history
sales_flat_quote
sales_flat_quote_address
sales_flat_quote_address_item
sales_flat_quote_item
sales_flat_quote_item_option
sales_flat_quote_payment
sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate
sales_flat_shipment
sales_flat_shipment_comment
sales_flat_shipment_grid
sales_flat_shipment_item
sales_flat_shipment_track
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_payment_transaction
sales_recurring_profile
sales_recurring_profile_order
sales_refunded_aggregated
sales_refunded_aggregated_order
wishlist
wishlist_item
wishlist_item_option
```

Make sure to not include the `enterprise_*` tables if you are not on Enterprise edition.

You can mysqldump out these tables with the following command:

> mysqldump -u DATABASE_USER -p DATABASE_NAME customer_address_entity customer_address_entity_datetime customer_address_entity_decimal customer_address_entity_int customer_address_entity_text customer_address_entity_varchar customer_entity customer_entity_datetime customer_entity_decimal customer_entity_int customer_entity_text customer_entity_varchar enterprise_customer_sales_flat_order enterprise_customer_sales_flat_order_address enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote enterprise_customer_sales_flat_quote_address enterprise_sales_creditmemo_grid_archive enterprise_sales_invoice_grid_archive enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive enterprise_sales_shipment_grid_archive sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly sales_flat_creditmemo sales_flat_creditmemo_comment sales_flat_creditmemo_grid sales_flat_creditmemo_item sales_flat_invoice sales_flat_invoice_comment sales_flat_invoice_grid sales_flat_invoice_item sales_flat_order sales_flat_order_address sales_flat_order_grid sales_flat_order_item sales_flat_order_payment sales_flat_order_status_history sales_flat_quote sales_flat_quote_address sales_flat_quote_address_item sales_flat_quote_item sales_flat_quote_item_option sales_flat_quote_payment sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate sales_flat_shipment sales_flat_shipment_comment sales_flat_shipment_grid sales_flat_shipment_item sales_flat_shipment_track sales_order_aggregated_created sales_order_aggregated_updated sales_order_tax sales_order_tax_item sales_payment_transaction sales_recurring_profile sales_recurring_profile_order sales_refunded_aggregated sales_refunded_aggregated_order wishlist wishlist_item wishlist_item_option > database.sql

Replacing `DATABASE_USER` and `DATABASE_NAME` with the ones located in your `local.xml` file.

If you'd like to update the entire database and migrate it across you can also just export the entire database with:

> mysqldump -u DATABASE_USER -p DATABASE_NAME > database.sql

Once you've transferred the files across to the new server (If there is one) Then it can then be imported with

> mysql -u DATABASE_USER -p DATABASE_NAME < database.sql

Hope that helps!

**Note: This isn't the most efficient method for updating customers, usually the use of the Import/Export functionality in Magento would work but the OP does not have access. If you're using this method, remember to backup the DB you're migrating to in case you need to restore.**

Comment: Don't know why this received a downvote.. will try and tell. I belive that it'll fail due to duplicate keys, but we'll find out. Thanks!